# ¿Que es mejor entre la herencia o la delegación para crear una clase segura para los subprocesos?

Tags: java

Necesito crear una clase `MySafeList` segura para los subprocesos desde la implementación no segura para subprocesos de `java.util.ArrayList <Double>`.
He hecho una nueva clase `MySafeList` que implemente los métodos `add()`, `size()` y `get()` basados en los métodos de la clase `java.util.ArrayList <Double>`(por ahora, no me preocupo por la sincronización). Utilizo la herencia pero ¿qué es mejor entre la herencia o la delegación?

```
import java.util.ArrayList<Double>

class MySafeList extends ArrayList<Double>{

    ArrayList<Double> mySafeList;

    public void add(Double d){
        mySafeList.add(d);
    }

    public int size(){
        return mySafeList.size();
    }

    public double get(int i){
        mySafeList.get(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ese código parece una mezcla entre delegar y heredar, no sé qué estás intentando hacer.

Comment: @PabloLozano una clase segura para utilizar subprocesos.

Answer (score -2):

Si quieres extender o heredar de una clase generalmente es porque vas a cambiar o extender su comportamiento.

La que muestras para empezar está limitada a Double, quizás pudieras dejarle el tipo abierto para que la pudieras reutilizar con otros tipos.

Y si a lo que te refieres como segura es para que esté sincronizada, lo único que requieres es :

```
ArrayList<Double> listaSincronizada = 
      Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Double>());
```

Ya tienes tu lista sincronizada.

Si quieres saber si es mejor heredar o delegar tendrías que explicar más de lo que hace tu clase.

Por lo que mencionas de "listaSegura", estoy suponiendo que la mejor opción seria "encapsularla". Encapsular limita los accesos a la misma.

Comment: entiendo que te moleste la respuesta pero tu clase no hace nada que no haga la que extiendes. No tiene sentido.

Comment: Esto es mas comentario que respuesta.